# Library Resources Not Private?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, shared-libraries

I've followed the developer documentation for implementing a library module in Android Studio. Everything works smoothly except my resources show up in auto-complete in my main module.

I created my module within the project (I did not import it, and I did not use jCenter), I've tried using

```
<public />
```

and

```
<public name="some_resource" type="string" />
```

with no luck. When I export the module as .aar and then switch to a different branch that does not have the module in it and then import the branch however the resources are correctly treated as private. However, ideally I would like to be able to keep the module inside of the project so that it can be edited freely.